# Search file for match, if not available go to next file

Tags: python, linux, search, file-handling

This program searches for files with that contain a string defined by the user, and reads though and runs some scripts based on the information within certain matching words, i.e. intermediate and depot, but it has come to light that more than one file will contain the string given but not intermediate etc. My question is how to I write it so the program will check the file for intermediate and if it's not there then search the next and so on?

Below is the current code in use.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
import sys, traceback


s_REG=raw_input('Please enter Reg number: ')

try:
    a = Popen(["grep -l %s /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/*/*.ini --exclude=\"/shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/*/conRtChp.ini\" " %s_REG], shell=True, stdout = PIPE)
    FILE_DIR = a.communicate()[0]
    FILE_DIR=FILE_DIR.rstrip('\n')
    FILE=open("%s" %FILE_DIR , 'r')
except IOError:
    print "REG DOES NOT EXIST PLEASE CHECK .INI FILE: error code U1001\n"
    print "Please consult Error Codes and meanings reference by viewing this program\n"
    sys.exit(0)

try:
# Read File into array
    for LINES in FILE:
        if LINES.strip() == '[intermediate]':
            break
    for LINES in FILE:
        if LINES.strip() == '[depotNum]':
        break
    if LINES.strip() == '[global]':
            break
        LINES = LINES.rstrip("\n").split(";")
# Remove Blank Lines and whitespace
        LINES = filter(None, LINES)
# Ignore any lines that have been commented out
        LINES = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), LINES)
        for I in range(len(LINES)):
    # Call the CrossRef Processor for each Reg to make sure for no differences
            call(["/shares/optiload/prog/utilPRG/indref.sh", "%s" %LINES[I]]) 
except:
    print "Cannot find Crossref creation script: error code U1002"
    print "Please consult Error Codes and meanings reference by viewing this program\n"
    sys.exit(0)
FILE.close()
try:
    call(["/shares/optiload/prog/utilPRG/sortSs.sh"])
except:
    print "Cannot find Crossref sort script: error code U1003"
    print "Please consult Error Codes and meanings reference by viewing this program\n"
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What I would suggest is to first get all the filenames in a list, then iterate that list,while opening each file and then using regular expressions to find the required pattern in the given contents of the file, if the pattern is not found then jumping on the next file name in the list and so on until the end of list is reached , its simple , and would require only 7-8 lines of code, does that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
#import re  -- This module can be used for more advanced processings

path = '/home/anmol/Desktop/test/testing/'#path of sample files

files = [fiile for fiile in os.listdir(path) if '~' not in fiile]
#this generates a list with the non-hidden files, hence using '~'
#os.listdir() returns a list of all the files in a given directory.

#os.listdir() = ['file 4.txt', 'file 5.txt', 'file 4.txt~', 'file 5.txt~', 
#'file2.txt', 'file1.txt~', 'file1.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file3.txt~', 'file2.txt~']

# After using '~' not in fiile
# files = ['file 4.txt', 'file 5.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file1.txt', 'file3.txt']

for file_name in files:
    document = open(path+file_name).read()    #returns a string
    refined_document = " ".join(document.split("\n"))   # replaces \n with a space
    if "intermediate" in refined_document or "depot" in refined_document:
        #main working condition
        print "The required word is found under :",file_name
```

Contents of file:

file1.txt

```
Hi this is the 
program and it doesnpt includes 
the required word!

Thanks!!
```

file2.txt

```
Hi!, This is the second
file and it does contains the 
word intermediate 

Thanks!!
```

file3.txt

```
Hello!! This is another file
and it also contains a 
word depot
hahahahah 

Thanks!!
```

file4.txt

```
Hi This is a file 
which contains both of them
as itermediadte of a depot
stands a human

Thanks!!
```

file5.txt

```
Hello , 
This file again contains garbage...
@#*$#YHGTGYBFDSW#$%^&*Q%EWFYB
syasftyaghdjasbv$^%&*OUSa
dsadhgvtgw67BR^&^(D87O D
adas dasjdhashdbs 89&^g 

Thanks!!
```

Comment: This is the most general way of doing this , it may be possible that you want to handle some other type of files rather than only text files , in that case you can ask for any change accordingly.